# Parse multiple JSON/VBA objects with VBA-JSON

Tags: json, excel, vba

I have the following JSON response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1354345345,
        "date": "2021-10-01T23:29:42.000000+02:00",
        "count": 0,
        "year": 2020,
        "area": 232,
        "numberList": [
            8693978
        ],
        "Property": {
            "PropertyID": 135005860000118,
            "PropertyNumber": 2244
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2345235345,
        "date": "2021-02-13T13:40:30.000000+01:00",
        "count": 2,
        "year": 2020,
        "area": 122,
        "numberList": [
            8693978
        ],
        "Property": {
            "PropertyID": 153005860001536,
            "PropertyNumber": 1555
        }
    }
]
```

Inside the array [], there can be several object {}, each with a value in "area". In this example, there are two objects in the array.

I am trying to parse the JSON via [VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON).

I've tried the following VBA code, but it will only return the names of each object item and not the value.

```
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(responseText)

For Each Item In Json
    For Each i In Item
        Debug.Print i
    Next
Next
```

VBA debug console will show:

```
id
date
count
year
area
numberList
Property
id
date
count
year
area
numberList
Property
```

How do I fetch the area of each object?

Comment: So, do you need the value of the two existing "area" keys? (232, 122)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JsonConverter.ParseJson(responseText)` creates an object keeping `Scripting` Dictionaries... So, they expose keys and items. Based on that logic, please try the next way of "area" values extracting:

1. The string you show misses a ":" character (replaced with ";").Here: **"area"; 232,**. It should be correct to be parsed...
2. The next code version will iterate between the object keys and items, extracted the value (item) for the key "area":

```
   Dim json As Object, strFile As String, responseText As String, dict, i As Long
   
   responseText = "the corrected string you show..."
  
   Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJSON(responseText)
   
    For Each dict In json
        For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
            If dict.Keys()(i) = "area" Then
                Debug.Print TypeName(dict), TypeName(dict.Keys()(i)), TypeName(dict.Items()(i))
                Debug.Print dict.Items()(i)
            End If
        Next i
    Next dict
```

Comment: The ";" was a typo - my bad! Code works perfect, thank you for the explanation and code example!

Comment: @2by I was supposing it was a typo, but I must confess that I couldn't imagine how to copy it (probably, returned by code) and having a typo... :)

Comment: I removed a lot of the response to make it simpler, must have happened in the process :)